# How to Add Expires headers on nginx

Tags: nginx

According to GTMetrix:

There are 6 static components without a far-future expiration date.

```
http://linuxedgr.disqus.com/recent_comments_widget.js?num_items=5&hide_mods=0&hide_avatars=0&avatar_size=32&excerpt_length=100
http://s7.addthis.com/js/300/addthis_widget.js#pubid=ra-548e3c553a19ddf3
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,700italic,400,700
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js
http://a.disquscdn.com/count.js
http://linuxedgr.disqus.com/count-data.js?1=egkatastasi-tou-nginx&1=eisagogi-ston-nginx&1=new-dedicated-server-in-da-house-me-5-euro&1=o-epimenon-nika&1=pos-mporo-na-kano-encrypt-kai-decrypt-arxeia-xrismopoiontas-to-openssl-toolkit&1=pos-sindeo-ena-domain-apo-tin-IPHost-me-tin-ip-tou-server-mou
```

At my  /etc/nginx/vhosts.d/www.linuxed.gr.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;

        # Δώσε το absolute path που εχεις τα αρχεία του website
    root /var/www/html/linuxed;

    # Όριστε το index file
    index index.html index.html index.php;

    # Δώσε το όνομα του domain και το alias
    # τα οποια πρεπει να τα εχει δηλώσει και στο /etc/hosts
    server_name www.linuxed.gr linuxed.gr;

        # Συμπίεση 
        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_comp_level 6;
        gzip_min_length  1100;
        gzip_buffers  16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
        gzip_proxied     any;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;        

    # specify a vary: accept-encoding header
        gzip_vary on;   

    # Όριστε μία 404 page
        error_page  404              /error-404.html;
        location = /error-404.html {
        root   /var/www/html/linuxed/;
        }  


        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        root   /usr/share/nginx/html/;
        }

        # Disable favicon.ico logging
        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        # Allow robots and disable logging
        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

    ############################
    # Leverage browser caching #
    ############################
    location ~*  \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js)$ {
            expires max;
            log_not_found off;
        add_header Pragma public;
            add_header Cache-Control "public";
        } 

    # Deny access to htaccess and htpasswd files
        location ~ /\.ht {
            deny  all;
        }
}
```

Also here's my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
    user nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;

pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
    use epoll;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;   

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log off;

    # Tcp_nopush causes nginx to attempt to send its HTTP response head in one packet, 
    # instead of using partial frames. This is useful for prepending headers before
    #  calling sendfile or for throughput optimization.
    tcp_nopush on;

    # don't buffer data-sends (disable Nagle algorithm). Good for sending frequent
    # small bursts of data in real time.
    tcp_nodelay on; 

    sendfile        on;

    # allow the server to close the connection after a client stops responding. 
    #Frees up socket-associated memory.
    reset_timedout_connection on;

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    client_body_buffer_size 10k;
    client_header_buffer_size 1k;
    client_max_body_size 8m;
    large_client_header_buffers 2 1k;

    client_body_timeout 12;
    client_header_timeout 12;
    keepalive_timeout 15;
    send_timeout 10;

    include conf.d/*.conf;
    include vhosts.d/*.conf;


}
```

I think my configuration is quite right. How ever I am getting this message at GTMetrix website. How can I fix that?

Comment: What message are you getting?   Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All 6 resources which GTMetrix pointed out are from ***external domains*** and the expiration headers were not set with far-future expiration date because they might get changed very frequently and thus caching them may not give desired results.

You cannot do any thing from your server side about the expiration header warnings for those external resource. What GTMetrix displays is just a warning which can be ignored.